# Cannot load Windows 7 from Grub 2 Menu

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I originally had Windows 7 installed in my system then decided to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside it. When the system boots I get the grub menu but when I select Windows 7 the Grub menu just reappears (but ubuntu loads just fine). I did find a number of threads with similar problems but the Boot Repair output for those threads appeared to be different from mine and I did not want to risk further problems by applying an incorrect "solution". I would really appreciate any help.

Here is the output from Boot Repair:

Link: [Complete Boot Repair Output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5763742/)

Sample Output:

```
Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 3June2013]
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda4: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda4 
                   and looks at sector 36725144 of the same hard drive 
                   for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                   in partition 94 for .
Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.04 
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

Comment: This is not the best answer, but you could install burg instead of grub. Here is the link to install http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-in-ubuntu/ . it does work on 13.04. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two Win 7 installations. one in sda 2 & other in sda 3. i would recommend you should format the sda 3 partition.

Comment: sda3 is a windows partition I created for misc. files

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you boot into Ubuntu. In there, go to the Dash and look for the terminal. Alternatively, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open it. In there, type the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should repair your grub and get windows to boot.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work :(